Where can I find information relating to how to read the output of `@code_typed`?
I am trying to do some diagnostics to find out why some functions in our codebase are slow.
These functions are complex, so I used a simple Fibonacci example to begin experimenting with @code_typed.
Here is the example code.
function nextfib(n)
    a = one(n)
    b = one(n)
    while b < n
        a, b = b, a + b
    end
    return b
end

The output from @code_typed is as follows.
julia> @code_typed nextfib(1)
CodeInfo(
1 ─      nothing::Nothing
2 ┄ %2 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %6)::Int64
│   %3 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %2)::Int64
│   %4 = Base.slt_int(%2, n)::Bool
└──      goto #4 if not %4
3 ─ %6 = Base.add_int(%3, %2)::Int64
└──      goto #2
4 ─      return %2
)

I would guess the output here is a language which has a name. (But I don't know what the name is. Is it a type of LLVM language?)
Where can I find information about how to read this output?

Some information is at Julia Developer Documentation / Documentation of of Julia's Internals / Julia SSA-form IR
For your example:
1 ─      nothing::Nothing
2 ┄ %2 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %6)::Int64
│   %3 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %2)::Int64
│   %4 = Base.slt_int(%2, n)::Bool
└──      goto #4 if not %4
3 ─ %6 = Base.add_int(%3, %2)::Int64
└──      goto #2
4 ─      return %2

Numbers like #1 refer to block numbers (at left margin).
Numbers like %2 refer to values.
Block 2 starts with %2 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %6), an assignment to value %2 from a Phi node. The Phi node encodes that,

when arriving at this block coming from block #1, the value comes from the constant 1, and
when arriving at this block coming from block #3, the value
comes from value %6.

The second line of the block, %3 = φ (#1 => 1, #3 => %2), has an assignment to value %3 from a Phi node.  This Phi node encodes that

when arriving at this block from block #1, the value comes from the constant 1, and
when arriving at this block from block #3, the value comes from
value %2.   The value %2 here is the value before entering this iteration of block #2 (not the value assigned by the first line of block #2).

From the linked documentation:

if multiple Phi nodes appear at the start of a basic block, they are run simultaneously.

